# recibir texto del campo li mediante jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Necesito tomar el valor del `li` seleccionado y pasarlo al `input` de búsqueda, pero solo recibo el primer elemento no importa cual seleccione

`.haja` es el `class` de `ul` y `.list` de los `list`, `var hola` debería tomar el elemento `this` al que se le hace click no?.

Solo recibo Nueva actividad.

```
$(".haja").click(function(){
    document.getElementById("is").value ="";
    var hola = $(".list", this).html();
    alert(hola);
      document.getElementById("is").value = hola;
      $(".haja").hide();

  });
```

**UPDATE **

```
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../images/utilidad/favicon.ico" />
  <!--Scripts-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $("ul li").click(function(){
    console.log($(this).html());
  });
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function show(){
    $(".haja").show();
  }
  </script>
  <!--Fin -->
  <title>Menu Administracion CB</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <!--El ul se crea desde buscador.js-->
 <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <div class="buscador" id="bs1"></div>
      <button class="btn btn-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Buscar</button>
  </form>
  <!--El ul de prueba tampoco funciona-->
    <ul>
     <li>Item 1</li>
     <li>Item 2</li>
     <li>Item 3</li>
     <li>Item 4</li>
   </ul>

  <!--SCRIPTS del ul si -->
  <script src="../js/buscador.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/app.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

El codigo que se crea el ul desde buscador.js es el siguiente

```
  'use strict';

class Search {

constructor(obj) {
    this.el = document.querySelector(obj.el);
    this.list = obj.list;
    this.init();
}

init() {
    let input, listContainer;
    this.el.innerHTML = `
        <input placeholder="Buscar aqui" onclick="show();" type="search" id="is" class="input form-control mr-sm-2"/>
        <ul class="is-visible list-group haja" id="searchList"></ul>
    `;
    input = document.querySelector('.input');
    listContainer = document.querySelector('#searchList');
    this.watch(input, this.list, listContainer);
}

watch(input, list, search) {
    input.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
        search.innerHTML = '';
        let value = input.value.toLowerCase(),
            listT = list.length,
            existe = 0;

        for (let i = 0; i < listT; i++) {
            let text = list[i].toLowerCase();
            if (value != '') {
                existe = ~text.indexOf(value);
                if (existe != 0) {
                    this.updateList(search, list[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }, false);
}

updateList(el, text) {
    el.innerHTML += `<li class="list">${text}</li>`;
}


}
```

Comment: Sebastian, por favor edita tu pregunta y pega tu código en lugar de poner una imagen. Tu pregunta tendrá mejor aceptación si sigues las [reglas de la comunidad](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 4):

Para capturar el contenido de un elemento usando `$(this)` debes asignar el evento `click` directamente a los elementos con los que se va a hacer la interacción y no a su elemento padre.

Ahora como recomendación, si estás usando **jQuery** entonces úsalo el mayor número de veces que sea posible `document.getElementById("is").value` es **JavaScript** nativo y pudiste resumir esa línea usando el selector de **Jquery**.

```js
$('ul li').click(function(){
  console.log($(this).html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: que error puedo tener si a pesar de que tengo el mismo codigo que explicaste no realiza el console.log? mi estructura es jquery body ul script /body. tampoco me funciona la solucion del compañero de mas abajo

Comment: @SebastianGutierrez si no te funciona el log puede ser que el selector lo estas haciendo mal, necesitaría ver más de tu código

Comment: probe lo mismo $('ul li').click(function(){
  console.log($(this).html());
}); (ya que por el momento es el unico ul que maneja la pagina) tambie lo reemplaze por ul .list pero tampoco dio resultados

Comment: @SebastianGutierrez en este caso necesitare más información, actualiza tu pregunta con el código escrito por favor y no en imagen y dime, ¿Usas alguna librería de listas?

Comment: @SebastianGutierrez hay algo que no entiendo, si con tu código funcionaba por que no funciona con el mio si realmente lo único que cambia es la lógica de la función? utiliza entonces los selectores que tenías antes pero siguiendo la lógica mia

Comment: editando, la verdad nose porque funciona en ninguno de los dos casos. De seguro es un error al posicionar lo scripts

Comment: el ul de prueba funciona si bajo bootstrap.js  pero el que creo yo sigue sin funcionar ayuda :c

Comment: @SebastianGutierrez u.u mi horario de trabajo terminó, no vuelvo por estos lados hasta el lunes si deseas te sigo ayudando ese día, espero que de igual forma encuentres una solución

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a tu código debería funcionar así:

```
let $myInput = $('#is')

$('#searchList li').click(function(){
  $myInput.val($(this).html())
})
```